# ¿Cómo detener un session_start en php?

Tags: php, session, mensajes

Tengo un proyecto en el cual hice un archivo llamado header y tiene desde el `<html>` hasta donde termina el header `</header>`.  Al inicio ingresé un `session_start();`, por si hay cuentas iniciadas, les aparezca el nombre en el header. Pero como tengo una carpeta admin y esta verifica si está iniciada la sesión admin, por lo que también tiene `session_start();`.

Cuando entro a la carpeta admin, la página me arroja un mensaje que dice:

> Notice: session_start(): Ignoring session_start() because a session is already active in...

¿Cómo le hago para ocultar el mensaje o de detener el `session_start()`?, ya que es inofensivo pero se ve mal ahí.

Comment: Lo que se me ocurre es que puedes condicionar el session_start, si existe una variable (isset(session[x])) entonces no inicies la sesión

Comment: gracias @betovaz81

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esto sería el modelo que uso yo por ejemplo...

Probablemente puedas mejorarlo, pero es un concepto base.

```
// Si la sesión no está iniciada, iníciala
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
// Si no existe nadie logeado en la sesion, mándalo a logearse
if (!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"])) {
    header("location: login.php");
    exit;
}
// Si la sesión existe, rescata y asigna los valores 
if (isset($_SESSION)) {
    $id         = $_SESSION["id"];
    $username   = $_SESSION["username"];
}
```

Acá te dejo la asignación inicial de variables en el login.php
loggedin es para ver si alguien inició sesión, y las otras variables son rescatadas de la consulta.

```
$_SESSION["loggedin"]   = true;
$_SESSION["id"]         = $id;
$_SESSION["username"]   = $username;
```